# Convert the script code to apply to Sheet1 only instead of all

Tags: javascript

Can someone please give me a hand?

I have the following two scripts that work properly, but they apply to all sheets.  I need to apply them only to Sheet1 and I can't do it.

SCRIPT ONE

```
function conditionalFormatting1() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(sheet => {
    sheet.clearConditionalFormatRules();
    //sheet.clearFormats();
    sheet.getRange('A3:P').clearFormat()
    sheet.getRange('A3:P').setHorizontalAlignment("left")
    var rules = [];
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "$A$1:P1", "=$A1>0", "#86aba5"));
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "$A$2:A2", "=$A2>0", "#76dffb"));
    rules.push(createRule(sheet, "$B$2:J2", "=$B2>0", "#e0ffff"));
    sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules);
  });
}

function createRule(sheet, rangeNotation, formula, color) {
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeNotation);
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
    .whenFormulaSatisfied(formula)
    .setBackground(color)
    .setRanges([range])
    .build();
  return rule;
}
```

---

SCRIPT TWO

```
function headersTable1() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
  sheet.setFrozenRows(2);
  var values = [
    ["Completed Date", "ID", "Last Name", "First Name", "Phone", "Personal Email"]
  ];
  var range = sheet.getRange("A2:F2");
  range.setValues(values);
  })
}
```

In advance, thanks so much.

I have tried the following but the code stops and gives error:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
```